# Unable to add delegate permissions between two azure ad applications(legacy) through powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

We have created two applications in azure ad applications(classic /legacy) e.g Application1 and Application2.
We are unable to add delegate permission of Application1 with in application2 using powershell. please suggest

MyApplication2 is already present in the AAD.
If I remove the code below it successfully creates an application.

```
$myappper = GetRequiredPermissions -reqsp $MyApp2 -requiredApplicationPermissions $ApplicationPermissions -requiredDelegatedPermissions $DelegatedPermissions
$requiredResourcesAccess.Add($myappper)
```

Following is the code:

```
    $applicationName = "Mapplication1"

    # Modify the homePage, appIdURI and logoutURI values to whatever valid URI you like. They don't need to be actual addresses.
    $guid = New-Guid
    $homePage = "http://localhost"
    $appIdURI = "https://xxxx.onmicrosoft.com/" + $guid
    $logoutURI = "http://localhost"

    # Set this to false to keep the application in your tenant.
    $removeApplicationWhenComplete = $false

    # Set this to false to limit consent for delegated permissions to a single user ($UserForDelegatedPermissions).
    $ConsentDelegatedPermissionsForAllUsers = $true

    # If your initial test call required delegate permissions, set this to true. The script will retrieve an access token using the 'password' grant type instead.
    $testCallRequiresDelegatePermissions = $false

    # This will export information about the application to a CSV located at C:\temp\.
    # The CSV will include the Client ID and Secret of the application, so keep it safe.
    $exportApplicationInfoToCSV = $true

    # These endpoints are called using GET method. Please modify the script below as required.
    $URIForApplicationPermissionCall = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/reports/getTenantSecureScores(period=1)/content"
    $URIForDelegatedPermissionCall = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users"

    # If using Delegated Permissions to execute a test call, you can specify username and password info here. 
    # I strongly recommend securing these and not including them directly on the script. 
    $UserForDelegatedPermissions = "user"
    $Password = "######"


    # Enter the required permissions below, separated by spaces eg: "Directory.Read.All Reports.Read.All Group.ReadWrite.All Directory.ReadWrite.All"
    $ApplicationPermissions = "Reports.Read.All"

    # Set DelegatePermissions to $null if you only require application permissions. 
    #$DelegatedPermissions = $null
    # Otherwise, include the required delegated permissions below.
    $DelegatedPermissions = "Directory.Read.All Group.ReadWrite.All"


    Function AddResourcePermission($requiredAccess, $exposedPermissions, $requiredAccesses, $permissionType) {
        foreach ($permission in $requiredAccesses.Trim().Split(" ")) {
            $reqPermission = $null
            $reqPermission = $exposedPermissions | Where-Object {$_.Value -contains $permission}
            Write-Host "Collected information for $($reqPermission.Value) of type $permissionType" -ForegroundColor Green
            $resourceAccess = New-Object Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess
            $resourceAccess.Type = $permissionType
            $resourceAccess.Id = $reqPermission.Id    
            $requiredAccess.ResourceAccess.Add($resourceAccess)
        }
    }

    Function GetRequiredPermissions($requiredDelegatedPermissions, $requiredApplicationPermissions, $reqsp) {
        $sp = $reqsp
        $appid = $sp.AppId
        $requiredAccess = New-Object Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.RequiredResourceAccess
        $requiredAccess.ResourceAppId = $appid
        $requiredAccess.ResourceAccess = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess]
        if ($requiredDelegatedPermissions) {
            AddResourcePermission $requiredAccess -exposedPermissions $sp.Oauth2Permissions -requiredAccesses $requiredDelegatedPermissions -permissionType "Scope"
        } 
        if ($requiredApplicationPermissions) {
            AddResourcePermission $requiredAccess -exposedPermissions $sp.AppRoles -requiredAccesses $requiredApplicationPermissions -permissionType "Role"
        }
        return $requiredAccess
    }

    Function GenerateAppKey ($fromDate, $durationInYears, $pw) {
        $endDate = $fromDate.AddYears($durationInYears) 
        $keyId = (New-Guid).ToString();
        $key = New-Object Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.PasswordCredential($null, $endDate, $keyId, $fromDate, $pw)
        return $key
    }

    Function CreateAppKey($fromDate, $durationInYears, $pw) {

        $testKey = GenerateAppKey -fromDate $fromDate -durationInYears $durationInYears -pw $pw

        while ($testKey.Value -match "\+" -or $testKey.Value -match "/") {
            Write-Host "Secret contains + or / and may not authenticate correctly. Regenerating..." -ForegroundColor Yellow
            $pw = ComputePassword
            $testKey = GenerateAppKey -fromDate $fromDate -durationInYears $durationInYears -pw $pw
        }
        Write-Host "Secret doesn't contain + or /. Continuing..." -ForegroundColor Green
        $key = $testKey

        return $key
    }

    Function ComputePassword {
        $aesManaged = New-Object "System.Security.Cryptography.AesManaged"
        $aesManaged.Mode = [System.Security.Cryptography.CipherMode]::CBC
        $aesManaged.Padding = [System.Security.Cryptography.PaddingMode]::Zeros
        $aesManaged.BlockSize = 128
        $aesManaged.KeySize = 256
        $aesManaged.GenerateKey()
        return [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($aesManaged.Key)
    }

    Function AddOAuth2PermissionGrants($DelegatedPermissions) {
        $resource = "https://graph.windows.net/"
        $client_id = $aadApplication.AppId
        $client_secret = $appkey.Value
        $authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenant_id"
        $tokenEndpointUri = "$authority/oauth2/token"
        $content = "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=$client_id&client_secret=$client_secret&resource=$resource"

        $Stoploop = $false
        [int]$Retrycount = "0"

        do {
            try {
                $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $tokenEndpointUri -Body $content -Method Post -UseBasicParsing
                Write-Host "Retrieved Access Token for Azure AD Graph API" -ForegroundColor Green
                # Assign access token
                $access_token = $response.access_token

                $headers = @{
                    Authorization = "Bearer $access_token"
                }

                if ($ConsentDelegatedPermissionsForAllUsers) {
                    $principal = "AllPrincipals"
                    $principalId = $null
                }
                else {
                    $principal = "Principal"
                    $principalId = (Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $UserForDelegatedPermissions).ObjectId
                }

                $postbody = @{
                    clientId    = $serviceprincipal.ObjectId
                    consentType = $principal
                    startTime   = ((get-date).AddDays(-1)).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
                    principalId = $principalId
                    resourceId  = $graphsp.ObjectId
                    scope       = $DelegatedPermissions
                    expiryTime  = ((get-date).AddYears(99)).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
                }

                $postbody = $postbody | ConvertTo-Json

                $body = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/oauth2PermissionGrants?api-version=1.6" -Body $postbody -Method POST -Headers $headers -ContentType "application/json"
                Write-Host "Created OAuth2PermissionGrants for $DelegatedPermissions" -ForegroundColor Green

                $Stoploop = $true
            }
            catch {
                if ($Retrycount -gt 5) {
                    Write-Host "Could not get create OAuth2PermissionGrants after 6 retries." -ForegroundColor Red
                    $Stoploop = $true
                }
                else {
                    Write-Host "Could not create OAuth2PermissionGrants yet. Retrying in 5 seconds..." -ForegroundColor DarkYellow
                    Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
                    $Retrycount ++
                }
            }
        }
        While ($Stoploop -eq $false)
    }


    function GetOrCreateMicrosoftGraphServicePrincipal {
        $graphsp = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -SearchString "Microsoft Graph"
        $myapp = Get-AzureADApplication -SearchString "MyApplication2"
        $sp = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -SearchString "MyApplication2"

        if (!$graphsp) {
            $graphsp = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -SearchString "Microsoft.Azure.AgregatorService"
        }
        if (!$graphsp) {
            Login-AzureRmAccount -Credential $credential -TenantId $customer.CustomerContextId
            New-AzureRmADServicePrincipal -ApplicationId "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000"
            $graphsp = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -SearchString "Microsoft Graph"
        }

        return $graphsp
    }

    Import-Module AzureAD
    $credential = Get-Credential
    Connect-AzureAd -Credential $credential

    #$customers = Get-AzureADContract -All $true

    #foreach ($customer in $customers) {
        Connect-AzureAd -Credential $credential -TenantId "#########################"

        Write-Host "Creating Azure AD App for $((Get-AzureADTenantDetail).displayName)"

        # Check for a Microsoft Graph Service Principal. If it doesn't exist already, create it.
        $graphsp = GetOrCreateMicrosoftGraphServicePrincipal

        $existingapp = $null
        $existingapp = get-azureadapplication -SearchString $applicationName
        if ($existingapp) {
            Remove-Azureadapplication -ObjectId $existingApp.objectId
        }

        $rsps = @()
        if ($graphsp) {
            $rsps += $graphsp
            $tenant_id = (Get-AzureADTenantDetail).ObjectId
            $tenantName = (Get-AzureADTenantDetail).DisplayName
            $azureadsp = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -SearchString "Windows Azure Active Directory"
            $MyApp2 = Get-azureadapplication -SearchString "MyApplication2"
            $rsps += $azureadsp
            $rsps += $MyApp2

            # Add Required Resources Access (Microsoft Graph)
            $requiredResourcesAccess = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.RequiredResourceAccess]
            $microsoftGraphRequiredPermissions = GetRequiredPermissions -reqsp $graphsp -requiredApplicationPermissions $ApplicationPermissions -requiredDelegatedPermissions $DelegatedPermissions
            $requiredResourcesAccess.Add($microsoftGraphRequiredPermissions)
            $myappper = GetRequiredPermissions -reqsp $MyApp2 -requiredApplicationPermissions $ApplicationPermissions -requiredDelegatedPermissions $DelegatedPermissions
            $requiredResourcesAccess.Add($myappper)

            if ($DelegatedPermissions) {
                Write-Host "Delegated Permissions specified, preparing permissions for Azure AD Graph API"
                # Add Required Resources Access (Azure AD Graph)
                $AzureADGraphRequiredPermissions = GetRequiredPermissions -reqsp $azureadsp -requiredApplicationPermissions "Directory.ReadWrite.All"
                $requiredResourcesAccess.Add($AzureADGraphRequiredPermissions)
            }


            # Get an application key
            $pw = ComputePassword
            $fromDate = [System.DateTime]::Now
            $appKey = CreateAppKey -fromDate $fromDate -durationInYears 2 -pw $pw

            Write-Host "Creating the AAD application $applicationName" -ForegroundColor Blue
            $aadApplication = New-AzureADApplication -DisplayName $applicationName `
                -HomePage $homePage `
                -ReplyUrls $homePage `
                -IdentifierUris $appIdURI `
                -LogoutUrl $logoutURI `
                -RequiredResourceAccess $requiredResourcesAccess `
                -PasswordCredentials $appKey

            # Creating the Service Principal for the application
            $servicePrincipal = New-AzureADServicePrincipal -AppId $aadApplication.AppId

            Write-Host "Assigning Permissions" -ForegroundColor Yellow

            # Assign application permissions to the application
            foreach ($app in $requiredResourcesAccess) {

                $reqAppSP = $rsps | Where-Object {$_.appid -contains $app.ResourceAppId}
                Write-Host "Assigning Application permissions for $($reqAppSP.displayName)" -ForegroundColor DarkYellow

                foreach ($resource in $app.ResourceAccess) {
                    if ($resource.Type -match "Role") {
                        New-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId $serviceprincipal.ObjectId `
                            -PrincipalId $serviceprincipal.ObjectId -ResourceId $reqAppSP.ObjectId -Id $resource.Id
                    }
                }

            }

            # Assign delegated permissions to the application
            if ($requiredResourcesAccess.ResourceAccess -match "Scope") {
                Write-Host "Delegated Permissions found. Assigning permissions to required user"  -ForegroundColor DarkYellow

                foreach ($app in $requiredResourcesAccess) {
                    $appDP = @()
                    $reqAppSP = $rsps | Where-Object {$_.appid -contains $app.ResourceAppId}

                    foreach ($resource in $app.ResourceAccess) {
                        if ($resource.Type -match "Scope") {
                            $permission = $graphsp.oauth2permissions | Where-Object {$_.id -contains $resource.Id}
                            $appDP += $permission.Value
                        }
                    }
                    if ($appDP) {
                        Write-Host "Adding $appDP to user" -ForegroundColor DarkYellow
                        $appDPString = $appDp -join " "
                        AddOAuth2PermissionGrants -DelegatedPermissions $appDPString
                    }
                }
            }

            Write-Host "App Created" -ForegroundColor Green

            # Define parameters for Microsoft Graph access token retrieval
            $client_id = $aadApplication.AppId;
            $client_secret = $appkey.Value
            $tenant_id = (Get-AzureADTenantDetail).ObjectId
            $resource = "https://graph.microsoft.com"
            $authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenant_id"
            $tokenEndpointUri = "$authority/oauth2/token"

            # Get the access token using grant type password for Delegated Permissions or grant type client_credentials for Application Permissions
            if ($DelegatedPermissions -and $testCallRequiresDelegatePermissions) { 
                $content = "grant_type=password&client_id=$client_id&client_secret=$client_secret&username=$UserForDelegatedPermissions&password=$Password&resource=$resource";
                $testCallUri = $UriForDelegatedPermissionCall
            }
            else {
                $content = "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=$client_id&client_secret=$client_secret&resource=$resource"
                $testCallUri = $UriForApplicationPermissionCall
            }


            # Try to execute the API call 6 times

            $Stoploop = $false
            [int]$Retrycount = "0"
            do {
                try {
                    $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $tokenEndpointUri -Body $content -Method Post -UseBasicParsing
                    Write-Host "Retrieved Access Token" -ForegroundColor Green
                    # Assign access token
                    $access_token = $response.access_token
                    $body = $null

                    $body = Invoke-RestMethod `
                        -Uri $testCallUri `
                        -Headers @{"Authorization" = "Bearer $access_token"} `
                        -ContentType "application/json" `
                        -Method GET

                    Write-Host "Retrieved Graph content" -ForegroundColor Green
                    $Stoploop = $true
                }
                catch {
                    if ($Retrycount -gt 6) {
                        Write-Host "Could not get Graph content after 7 retries." -ForegroundColor Red
                        $Stoploop = $true
                    }
                    else {
                        Write-Host "Could not get Graph content. Retrying in 5 seconds..." -ForegroundColor DarkYellow
                        Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
                        $Retrycount ++
                    }
                }
            }
            While ($Stoploop -eq $false)

            if ($exportApplicationInfoToCSV) {
                $appProperties = @{
                    ApplicationName        = $ApplicationName
                    TenantName             = $tenantName
                    TenantId               = $tenant_id
                    clientId               = $client_id
                    clientSecret           = $client_secret
                    ApplicationPermissions = $ApplicationPermissions
                    DelegatedPermissions   = $DelegatedPermissions
                }

                $AppInfo = New-Object PSObject -Property $appProperties
                $AppInfo | Select-Object ApplicationName, TenantName, TenantId, clientId, clientSecret, `
                    ApplicationPermissions, DelegatedPermissions | Export-Csv C:\temp\AzureADApps.csv -Append -NoTypeInformation
            }

            if ($removeApplicationWhenComplete) {
                Remove-AzureADApplication -ObjectId $aadApplication.ObjectId
                $confirmRemoval = $null
                try {
                    $confirmRemoval = Get-AzureADApplication -ObjectId $aadApplication.ObjectId
                }
                catch {
                    Write-Host "Application Removed" -ForegroundColor Green
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            Write-Host "Microsoft Graph Service Principal could not be found or created" -ForegroundColor Red
        }

        # Export CSV of Secure Score
        if ($body.secureScore) {
            Write-Host "Exporting Secure Score to CSV" -ForegroundColor Green
            $createdDateString = "$($body.createdDate.Year)-$($body.createdDate.Month)-$($body.createdDate.Day)"
            $body | Add-Member TenantName $tenantName
            $body | Add-Member dateCreated $createdDateString
            $createdDateString = $body | Select-Object @{n = "createdDate"; e = {"$($_.createdDate.Year)-$($_.createdDate.Month)-$($_.createdDate.Day)"}}
            $body | Select-Object TenantName, TenantId, DateCreated, secureScore, maxSecureScore, accountScore, dataScore, deviceScore, averageSecureScore `
                | Export-Csv C:\temp\SecureScore.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
        }
    #}
```

Comment: what exactly is "we are unable" what code you have at moment? what did you tried?

Comment: Update the description with the code..

Comment: delegate permissions are added through the GraphApi `oauth2PermissionGrants` resource, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/oauth2permissiongrant?view=graph-rest-beta

Answer (score 0):

Delegate permissions are added with the GraphApi [oAuth2PermissionGrant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/oauth2permissiongrant?view=graph-rest-beta) Resource...

See this example function below:

You need to provide a `token`,`Tenant Name`,`Service Principal Id`, `Graph API Id` and 
`ScopePermission` (for example `Reports.Read.All`)

Hope this can help...

```
Function Grant-Oauth2Permissions
{
Param(
$Token,
$Tenant,
$ServicePrincipalObjectID, # Service Principal Id
$ResourceObjectID, # e.g Graph API Id
$ScopePermission # e.g "Reports.Read.All"
)

$authHeader = @{
'Authorization'=$token.CreateAuthorizationHeader();
}

$body = @"
{
    "odata.type": "Microsoft.DirectoryServices.OAuth2PermissionGrant",
    "clientId": "$ServicePrincipalObjectID",
    "consentType": "AllPrincipals",
    "principalId": null,
    "resourceId": "$ResourceObjectID",
    "scope": "$ScopePermission",
    "startTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "expiryTime": "9000-01-01T00:00:00"
}
"@

Try {
$uri = "https://graph.windows.net/$Tenant/oauth2PermissionGrants?api-version=1.6"
$Result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri –Headers $authHeader –Method Post -ContentType 'application/json' -Body $body
return $Result
}
    catch
    {
    return $Error[0].Exception
    }


}
```

Comment: Hi Avshalom,
Thanks for the response. I have tried with your code and I am getting the response error as  "Invalid domain name in the request url.".
Following is the  my URI https://graph.windows.net/xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2PermissionGrants.
Could you please let me know is there any issue with the URI

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I was assigning "Role"(Application permission) instead of "Scope"(Delegate), also incorrect permission(Directory.ReadWrite.All) the correct permission is user_impersonation.

Whenever we want to provide the delegate permission for an ad app in another ad app(user created apps) we have to set the "user_impersonation" delegate permission.
Below is the modified script.

$applicationName = "Mapplication1"

```
# Modify the homePage, appIdURI and logoutURI values to whatever valid URI you like. They don't need to be actual addresses.
$guid = New-Guid
$homePage = "http://localhost"
$appIdURI = "https://xxxx.onmicrosoft.com/" + $guid
$logoutURI = "http://localhost"

# Set this to false to keep the application in your tenant.
$removeApplicationWhenComplete = $false

# Set this to false to limit consent for delegated permissions to a single user ($UserForDelegatedPermissions).
$ConsentDelegatedPermissionsForAllUsers = $true

# If your initial test call required delegate permissions, set this to true. The script will retrieve an access token using the 'password' grant type instead.
$testCallRequiresDelegatePermissions = $false

# This will export information about the application to a CSV located at C:\temp\.
# The CSV will include the Client ID and Secret of the application, so keep it safe.
$exportApplicationInfoToCSV = $true

# These endpoints are called using GET method. Please modify the script below as required.
$URIForApplicationPermissionCall = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/reports/getTenantSecureScores(period=1)/content"
$URIForDelegatedPermissionCall = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users"

# If using Delegated Permissions to execute a test call, you can specify username and password info here. 
# I strongly recommend securing these and not including them directly on the script. 
$UserForDelegatedPermissions = "user"
$Password = "######"


# Enter the required permissions below, separated by spaces eg: "Directory.Read.All Reports.Read.All Group.ReadWrite.All Directory.ReadWrite.All"
$ApplicationPermissions = "Reports.Read.All"

# Set DelegatePermissions to $null if you only require application permissions. 
#$DelegatedPermissions = $null
# Otherwise, include the required delegated permissions below.
$DelegatedPermissions = "Directory.Read.All Group.ReadWrite.All"


Function AddResourcePermission($requiredAccess, $exposedPermissions, $requiredAccesses, $permissionType) {
    foreach ($permission in $requiredAccesses.Trim().Split(" ")) {
        $reqPermission = $null
        $reqPermission = $exposedPermissions | Where-Object {$_.Value -contains $permission}
        Write-Host "Collected information for $($reqPermission.Value) of type $permissionType" -ForegroundColor Green
        $resourceAccess = New-Object Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess
        $resourceAccess.Type = $permissionType
        $resourceAccess.Id = $reqPermission.Id    
        $requiredAccess.ResourceAccess.Add($resourceAccess)
    }
}

Function GetRequiredPermissions($requiredDelegatedPermissions, $requiredApplicationPermissions, $reqsp) {
    $sp = $reqsp
    $appid = $sp.AppId
    $requiredAccess = New-Object Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.RequiredResourceAccess
    $requiredAccess.ResourceAppId = $appid
    $requiredAccess.ResourceAccess = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess]
    if ($requiredDelegatedPermissions) {
        AddResourcePermission $requiredAccess -exposedPermissions $sp.Oauth2Permissions -requiredAccesses $requiredDelegatedPermissions -permissionType "Scope"
    } 
    if ($requiredApplicationPermissions) {
        AddResourcePermission $requiredAccess -exposedPermissions $sp.AppRoles -requiredAccesses $requiredApplicationPermissions -permissionType "Role"
    }
    return $requiredAccess
}

Function GenerateAppKey ($fromDate, $durationInYears, $pw) {
    $endDate = $fromDate.AddYears($durationInYears) 
    $keyId = (New-Guid).ToString();
    $key = New-Object Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.PasswordCredential($null, $endDate, $keyId, $fromDate, $pw)
    return $key
}

Function CreateAppKey($fromDate, $durationInYears, $pw) {

    $testKey = GenerateAppKey -fromDate $fromDate -durationInYears $durationInYears -pw $pw

    while ($testKey.Value -match "\+" -or $testKey.Value -match "/") {
        Write-Host "Secret contains + or / and may not authenticate correctly. Regenerating..." -ForegroundColor Yellow
        $pw = ComputePassword
        $testKey = GenerateAppKey -fromDate $fromDate -durationInYears $durationInYears -pw $pw
    }
    Write-Host "Secret doesn't contain + or /. Continuing..." -ForegroundColor Green
    $key = $testKey

    return $key
}

Function ComputePassword {
    $aesManaged = New-Object "System.Security.Cryptography.AesManaged"
    $aesManaged.Mode = [System.Security.Cryptography.CipherMode]::CBC
    $aesManaged.Padding = [System.Security.Cryptography.PaddingMode]::Zeros
    $aesManaged.BlockSize = 128
    $aesManaged.KeySize = 256
    $aesManaged.GenerateKey()
    return [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($aesManaged.Key)
}

Function AddOAuth2PermissionGrants($DelegatedPermissions) {
    $resource = "https://graph.windows.net/"
    $client_id = $aadApplication.AppId
    $client_secret = $appkey.Value
    $authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenant_id"
    $tokenEndpointUri = "$authority/oauth2/token"
    $content = "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=$client_id&client_secret=$client_secret&resource=$resource"

    $Stoploop = $false
    [int]$Retrycount = "0"

    do {
        try {
            $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $tokenEndpointUri -Body $content -Method Post -UseBasicParsing
            Write-Host "Retrieved Access Token for Azure AD Graph API" -ForegroundColor Green
            # Assign access token
            $access_token = $response.access_token

            $headers = @{
                Authorization = "Bearer $access_token"
            }

            if ($ConsentDelegatedPermissionsForAllUsers) {
                $principal = "AllPrincipals"
                $principalId = $null
            }
            else {
                $principal = "Principal"
                $principalId = (Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $UserForDelegatedPermissions).ObjectId
            }

            $postbody = @{
                clientId    = $serviceprincipal.ObjectId
                consentType = $principal
                startTime   = ((get-date).AddDays(-1)).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
                principalId = $principalId
                resourceId  = $graphsp.ObjectId
                scope       = $DelegatedPermissions
                expiryTime  = ((get-date).AddYears(99)).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
            }

            $postbody = $postbody | ConvertTo-Json

            $body = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/oauth2PermissionGrants?api-version=1.6" -Body $postbody -Method POST -Headers $headers -ContentType "application/json"
            Write-Host "Created OAuth2PermissionGrants for $DelegatedPermissions" -ForegroundColor Green

            $Stoploop = $true
        }
        catch {
            if ($Retrycount -gt 5) {
                Write-Host "Could not get create OAuth2PermissionGrants after 6 retries." -ForegroundColor Red
                $Stoploop = $true
            }
            else {
                Write-Host "Could not create OAuth2PermissionGrants yet. Retrying in 5 seconds..." -ForegroundColor DarkYellow
                Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
                $Retrycount ++
            }
        }
    }
    While ($Stoploop -eq $false)
}


function GetOrCreateMicrosoftGraphServicePrincipal {
    $graphsp = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -SearchString "Microsoft Graph"
    $myapp = Get-AzureADApplication -SearchString "MyApplication2"
    $sp = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -SearchString "MyApplication2"

    if (!$graphsp) {
        $graphsp = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -SearchString "Microsoft.Azure.AgregatorService"
    }
    if (!$graphsp) {
        Login-AzureRmAccount -Credential $credential -TenantId $customer.CustomerContextId
        New-AzureRmADServicePrincipal -ApplicationId "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000"
        $graphsp = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -SearchString "Microsoft Graph"
    }

    return $graphsp
}

Import-Module AzureAD
$credential = Get-Credential
Connect-AzureAd -Credential $credential

#$customers = Get-AzureADContract -All $true

#foreach ($customer in $customers) {
    Connect-AzureAd -Credential $credential -TenantId "#########################"

    Write-Host "Creating Azure AD App for $((Get-AzureADTenantDetail).displayName)"

    # Check for a Microsoft Graph Service Principal. If it doesn't exist already, create it.
    $graphsp = GetOrCreateMicrosoftGraphServicePrincipal

    $existingapp = $null
    $existingapp = get-azureadapplication -SearchString $applicationName
    if ($existingapp) {
        Remove-Azureadapplication -ObjectId $existingApp.objectId
    }

    $rsps = @()
    if ($graphsp) {
        $rsps += $graphsp
        $tenant_id = (Get-AzureADTenantDetail).ObjectId
        $tenantName = (Get-AzureADTenantDetail).DisplayName
        $azureadsp = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -SearchString "Windows Azure Active Directory"
        $MyApp2 = Get-azureadapplication -SearchString "MyApplication2"
        $rsps += $azureadsp
        $rsps += $MyApp2

        # Add Required Resources Access (Microsoft Graph)
        $requiredResourcesAccess = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.RequiredResourceAccess]
        $microsoftGraphRequiredPermissions = GetRequiredPermissions -reqsp $graphsp -requiredApplicationPermissions $ApplicationPermissions -requiredDelegatedPermissions $DelegatedPermissions
        $requiredResourcesAccess.Add($microsoftGraphRequiredPermissions)
        $myappper = GetRequiredPermissions -reqsp $MyApp2 -requiredApplicationPermissions $ApplicationPermissions -requiredDelegatedPermissions $DelegatedPermissions
        $requiredResourcesAccess.Add($myappper)

        if ($DelegatedPermissions) {
            Write-Host "Delegated Permissions specified, preparing permissions for Azure AD Graph API"
            # Add Required Resources Access (Azure AD Graph)
            $AzureADGraphRequiredPermissions = GetRequiredPermissions -reqsp $azureadsp -requiredDelegatedPermissions "user_impersonation"
            $requiredResourcesAccess.Add($AzureADGraphRequiredPermissions)
        }


        # Get an application key
        $pw = ComputePassword
        $fromDate = [System.DateTime]::Now
        $appKey = CreateAppKey -fromDate $fromDate -durationInYears 2 -pw $pw

        Write-Host "Creating the AAD application $applicationName" -ForegroundColor Blue
        $aadApplication = New-AzureADApplication -DisplayName $applicationName `
            -HomePage $homePage `
            -ReplyUrls $homePage `
            -IdentifierUris $appIdURI `
            -LogoutUrl $logoutURI `
            -RequiredResourceAccess $requiredResourcesAccess `
            -PasswordCredentials $appKey

        # Creating the Service Principal for the application
        $servicePrincipal = New-AzureADServicePrincipal -AppId $aadApplication.AppId

        Write-Host "Assigning Permissions" -ForegroundColor Yellow

        # Assign application permissions to the application
        foreach ($app in $requiredResourcesAccess) {

            $reqAppSP = $rsps | Where-Object {$_.appid -contains $app.ResourceAppId}
            Write-Host "Assigning Application permissions for $($reqAppSP.displayName)" -ForegroundColor DarkYellow

            foreach ($resource in $app.ResourceAccess) {
                if ($resource.Type -match "Role") {
                    New-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId $serviceprincipal.ObjectId `
                        -PrincipalId $serviceprincipal.ObjectId -ResourceId $reqAppSP.ObjectId -Id $resource.Id
                }
            }

        }

        # Assign delegated permissions to the application
        if ($requiredResourcesAccess.ResourceAccess -match "Scope") {
            Write-Host "Delegated Permissions found. Assigning permissions to required user"  -ForegroundColor DarkYellow

            foreach ($app in $requiredResourcesAccess) {
                $appDP = @()
                $reqAppSP = $rsps | Where-Object {$_.appid -contains $app.ResourceAppId}

                foreach ($resource in $app.ResourceAccess) {
                    if ($resource.Type -match "Scope") {
                        $permission = $graphsp.oauth2permissions | Where-Object {$_.id -contains $resource.Id}
                        $appDP += $permission.Value
                    }
                }
                if ($appDP) {
                    Write-Host "Adding $appDP to user" -ForegroundColor DarkYellow
                    $appDPString = $appDp -join " "
                    AddOAuth2PermissionGrants -DelegatedPermissions $appDPString
                }
            }
        }

        Write-Host "App Created" -ForegroundColor Green

        # Define parameters for Microsoft Graph access token retrieval
        $client_id = $aadApplication.AppId;
        $client_secret = $appkey.Value
        $tenant_id = (Get-AzureADTenantDetail).ObjectId
        $resource = "https://graph.microsoft.com"
        $authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenant_id"
        $tokenEndpointUri = "$authority/oauth2/token"

        # Get the access token using grant type password for Delegated Permissions or grant type client_credentials for Application Permissions
        if ($DelegatedPermissions -and $testCallRequiresDelegatePermissions) { 
            $content = "grant_type=password&client_id=$client_id&client_secret=$client_secret&username=$UserForDelegatedPermissions&password=$Password&resource=$resource";
            $testCallUri = $UriForDelegatedPermissionCall
        }
        else {
            $content = "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=$client_id&client_secret=$client_secret&resource=$resource"
            $testCallUri = $UriForApplicationPermissionCall
        }


        # Try to execute the API call 6 times

        $Stoploop = $false
        [int]$Retrycount = "0"
        do {
            try {
                $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $tokenEndpointUri -Body $content -Method Post -UseBasicParsing
                Write-Host "Retrieved Access Token" -ForegroundColor Green
                # Assign access token
                $access_token = $response.access_token
                $body = $null

                $body = Invoke-RestMethod `
                    -Uri $testCallUri `
                    -Headers @{"Authorization" = "Bearer $access_token"} `
                    -ContentType "application/json" `
                    -Method GET

                Write-Host "Retrieved Graph content" -ForegroundColor Green
                $Stoploop = $true
            }
            catch {
                if ($Retrycount -gt 6) {
                    Write-Host "Could not get Graph content after 7 retries." -ForegroundColor Red
                    $Stoploop = $true
                }
                else {
                    Write-Host "Could not get Graph content. Retrying in 5 seconds..." -ForegroundColor DarkYellow
                    Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
                    $Retrycount ++
                }
            }
        }
        While ($Stoploop -eq $false)

        if ($exportApplicationInfoToCSV) {
            $appProperties = @{
                ApplicationName        = $ApplicationName
                TenantName             = $tenantName
                TenantId               = $tenant_id
                clientId               = $client_id
                clientSecret           = $client_secret
                ApplicationPermissions = $ApplicationPermissions
                DelegatedPermissions   = $DelegatedPermissions
            }

            $AppInfo = New-Object PSObject -Property $appProperties
            $AppInfo | Select-Object ApplicationName, TenantName, TenantId, clientId, clientSecret, `
                ApplicationPermissions, DelegatedPermissions | Export-Csv C:\temp\AzureADApps.csv -Append -NoTypeInformation
        }

        if ($removeApplicationWhenComplete) {
            Remove-AzureADApplication -ObjectId $aadApplication.ObjectId
            $confirmRemoval = $null
            try {
                $confirmRemoval = Get-AzureADApplication -ObjectId $aadApplication.ObjectId
            }
            catch {
                Write-Host "Application Removed" -ForegroundColor Green
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "Microsoft Graph Service Principal could not be found or created" -ForegroundColor Red
    }

    # Export CSV of Secure Score
    if ($body.secureScore) {
        Write-Host "Exporting Secure Score to CSV" -ForegroundColor Green
        $createdDateString = "$($body.createdDate.Year)-$($body.createdDate.Month)-$($body.createdDate.Day)"
        $body | Add-Member TenantName $tenantName
        $body | Add-Member dateCreated $createdDateString
        $createdDateString = $body | Select-Object @{n = "createdDate"; e = {"$($_.createdDate.Year)-$($_.createdDate.Month)-$($_.createdDate.Day)"}}
        $body | Select-Object TenantName, TenantId, DateCreated, secureScore, maxSecureScore, accountScore, dataScore, deviceScore, averageSecureScore `
            | Export-Csv C:\temp\SecureScore.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
    }
#}
```